# TFS 2012 - Email Alerts not working

Tags: email, tfs-alerts

We have a TFS 2012 server and have tried to enable email alerts. However, we never receive them.

I have set up both team alerts and alerts specific to my account. When configuring the SMTP settings in the TFS Admin Console, I have tried leaving the credentials blank, and also using my own credentials. Neither works.

I have also created a simple console app in C# using the `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` class to test emails, both with and without my credentials, from the TFS server and it works.

The Event Logs don't show any relevant error messages.

How can I troubleshoot and fix this issue?

### Update

Using the information in this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2009/10/28/tfs2010-diagnosing-email-and-soap-subscription-failures.aspx), I was able to extract the following error message from the database job history table.

```
elapsed time: 00:00:00.5255295, sql calls: 35, sql connect time: 00:00:00, sql execute time: 00:00:00.0311960, non-sql time: 00:00:00.4943335 (94%), cpu time: 00:00:00.0312002 ( 5.9%), avg connect time: 0.00 ms, avg execute time:  0.9 ms. All methods quick. All sql calls quick. CollectionError: CreateEvent != TransformEvents. CollectionError: AfterReadSubscription != ExpandEvents. CollectionError: RemoveRestrictedContent != FilterNotification. CollectionError: RemoveRestrictedContent != SendNotifications.
There were errors or warnings during notification delivery.

0/0 emails delivered.
0/0 soap notifications delivered. 
1 errors.
0 warnings.

-------------------------------
Notification not delivered due to error during filtering of restricted content.

Notification: WorkItemChangedEvent (DeliveryType: EmailHtml; Address: )

Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider..ctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(String name, Object[] args)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create(String algName)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.Alm.ConversationThread.Create(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, ToolType toolType, Byte artifactType, Int32 artifactId, String topic, DateTime creationDate)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.NotificationFilter.RemoveRestrictedContent(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, String server, TeamFoundationIdentity[] userIdentities, XmlDocument eventCopy, Restriction[]& restrictions)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.JobService.Extensions.Core.NotificationJobExtension.FilterNotification(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, TeamFoundationIdentity subscriber, IEnumerable`1 filters, TeamFoundationNotification notification)
```

As described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2550971/en-us), I have checked **Local Security Policy** for the *Security Settings->Local Policies->Security Options->"System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption, hashing, and signing"* value and it was already set to **disabled**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the **Visual Studio Team Foundation Background Job Agent** service fixed this particular error for me.